# Reading files from own domain results in 404

Tags: php, apache

When I try to use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to read something like http://example.com/python/json/ from http://example.com/ I should be getting a JSON response, but instead I get a 404 error. Using curl or any other method outside my own domain works perfectly well.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/python/json/'); => 404
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com'); => OK
```

The same script works on my laptop, but I can't figure out what the difference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like example.com is not the default domain for the IP address and that file_get_contents uses HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1 and/or does not send a Host: header. Try the curl support in PHP instead:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Alternatively the /etc/hosts file sets the wrong IP address for example.com.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the domain name to IP address and we're all set.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out to be that someone had hard-set the ip in /etc/hosts to an old dynamic IP before we switched to static. Thanks for inadvertently helping me too!

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with the domain, maybe? Of course, you don't want to reveal it here, so you might have a bit to do, but I guess the sanity check would be that you can access that URL via a web browser (or command line tool such as GET if you're command-line only).

You could also just ping and/or traceroute to the domain - the results may well be illuminating.